# Regex - replace blank spaces in line (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, tags

I have a document with multiple information. What I want is to build a Notepad++ Regex replace function, that finds the following lines in the document and replaces the blank spaces between the "" with an underline (_).

Example:
The line is:

```
&LOG Part: "NAME TEST.zip"
```

The result should be:

```
&LOG Part: "NAME_TEST.zip"
```

The perfect solution would be that the regex finds the &LOG Part: "NAME TEST.zip" lines and replaces the blank space with an underline.

What I have tried for now is this expression to find the text between the " ":

```
\"[^"]*\"
```

It should do it, but I don't know which expression to use to replace the blank spaces with an underline.

Anyone could help with a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\"[^"]*\"` will only match whole substrings from `"` up to another closest `"` without matching individual spaces you want to replace.

Since Notepad++ does not support infinite width lookbehind, the only possible solution is using the `\G` - based regex to set the boundaries and use multiple matching (this one will replace consecutive spaces with 1 `_`):

```
(?:"|(?!^)\G)\K([^ "]*) +(?=[^"]*")
```

Or (if each space should be replaced with an underscore):

```
(?:"|(?!^)\G)\K([^ "]*) (?=[^"]*")
```

And replace with `$1_`. If you need to restrict to replacing inside `&LOG Part` only, just add it to the beginning:

```
(?:&LOG Part:\s*"|(?!^)\G)\K([^ "]*) (?=[^"]*")
```

[image]

A human-readable explanation of the regex:

- `(?:"|(?!^)\G)\K` - Find a `"`, or, with each subsequent successful match, the end of the previous successful match position, and omit all the text in the buffer (thanks to `\K`)
- `([^ "]*) - (Group 1, accessed with`$1`from the replacement pattern) 0+ characters other than a space and`"`
- `+` - one or more literal spaces (replace with `\h` to match all horizontal whitespace, or `\s` to match any whitespace)
- `(?=[^"]*")` - check if there is a double quote ahead of the current position

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have also other strings that should maintain unaffected:

Example:
&LOG Part: "NAME TEST.zip"
&LOG Cloning: "TEST_TEST"
&LOG Container: "BLA BLA"

Only the &LOG Part line should be taken into account and the spaces replaced with underlines between the " ". 

All other lines (Cloning, Container) should remain unaffected.

As I am a newbie at this, can you please recommend an other solution to Notepad++ or would it be possible to use it anyways? 

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation! It works perfectly!